# Like operator including NULL with unique identifier format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like my select statement to pull up both NULL values and when the field is not empty using SSMS.

My kid field  is either null or contains a identifier with the following type of format:

```
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

If I leave off the where with the kid field, I got both options. I want in the event someone  wants to filter the results, they tweak the entry in the declare versus the where statement.

```
DECLARE Kid VARCHAR = '%'
```

Shows results of all instances (including NULL).

```
DECLARE kid VARCHAR = '50000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Filter results to only show instances

```
WHERE kid = '50000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

The way I got it to work seems inefficient?

```
select 
    Coalesce(kid, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') as kid
where 
    Coalesce(kid, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') like @kid
```

So when `Declare @kid ='%'` it gives me both, `Declare @kid='50000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'`, it gives me only those results.

Is there a prettier method?

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: `where kid like @kid or kid is null`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT kid FROM tbl WHERE (kid = @kid OR @kid IS NULL)
```

Using `OR @var IS NULL` is my preferred method to achieve this. If you set the variable to NULL, you'll get all rows because the OR clause always evaluates to TRUE. If you set a specific value, you'll only get rows with that value.

```
DECLARE @kid VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL --This will return everything    
DECLARE @kid VARCHAR(MAX) = '50000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' --This returns one
```

Comment: the OR doesn't work because I get error  Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier with NULL in the declare.

Comment: I did not get a conversion error, but if you are just declare as UNIQUEIDENTIFIER instead of VARCHAR.